# File name missing in REST API via HTTP Post

Tags: java, json, rest

I am doing a program which can take the file as input and send http://IPaddress:port_number/etc via REST API HTTP Post method, it will return me my file information in JSON format but in the return of my JSON data, I found out my file name and file type were missing. I only have two program doing the job ,one is sending the file to my server which install in VMware and one is receiving the JSON data from my server, my server only installed a malware scanning engine only  
 Here is my JSON data return from my server

```
{  
   "data_id":"7860ee33d8f14f8f931860dcf97d69a2",
   "file_info":{  
      "display_name":"",
      "file_size":289,
      "file_type":"Not available",
      "file_type_description":"Not available",
      "md5":"b294bdea53f3a038d263d8b2e7cafbbc",
      "sha1":"b869fd379cb9743b6c0994494f3ea91a133622cd",
      "sha256":"0f88b399aa65ad75a4e0d1d03acfd31731c68ea54d5f4f5053d6904d192e5e22",
      "upload_timestamp":"2016-11-21T09:48:58.675Z" },
```

I had tested several code in online but it's also fail to display the file name in the JSON data, **display_name** will be the file name for my file. May I know is it because some information being miss out in the header and how do I include the file name during the return JSON data ? 
 Here is my java source code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    public class SentFile {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {

          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.25:8008/file");
         // File file = new File("testScanFile.txt");
         //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
          FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("testScanFile.txt"));
        //  String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType("testScanFile.txt");
          HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
             //    .addBinaryBody("bin", new File("testScanFile.txt"),ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON,"testScanFile.txt").build();
                   .addPart("display_name", bin)
               //    .addPart("file",bin);
                   .build();
        //   post.addHeader("content-type","application/json");
        //   post.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
           post.setEntity(reqEntity);
          //InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
         // post.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           // System.out.println(line);
           PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("data_id.txt"));
           ps.print(line);
           ps.close();
          }
     }  
    }
```

Comment: i guess the request is not sending the file name, just the file body. Maybe there is a missing field that should be filled with a string

Comment: @nandsito - I found out there's missing header value for the file name, may I know how to set base on my java code ? can provide any related link ?

Comment: i can't. Only the server knows how the request should be built to include the missing information